# R Minimum Value from Datatable Not Equal to a Particular Value

Tags: r, minimum

1. How do I find the minimum value from an R data table other than a particular value?

   For example, there could be zeroes in the data table and the goal would be to find the minimum non zero value.

   I tried using the `sapply` with `min`, but am not sure how to specify the extra criteria that we have so that the minimum is not equal to a certain value.
2. More generally, How do we find the minimum from a data table not equal to any element from a list of possible values?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find the minimum value from a vector while *excluding* certain values from that vector, then you can use `%in%`:

```
v <- c(1:10)           # values 1 .. 10
v.exclude <- c(1, 2)   # exclude the values 1 and 2 from consideration
min.exclude <- min(v[!v %in% v.exclude])
```

The logic won't change much if you are using a column from a data table/frame.  In this case you can just replace the vector `v` with the apropriate column.  If you have your excluded values in a list, then you can flatten it to produce your `v.exclude` vector.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working with a `data.frame`

### Data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 b = c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,50,60))
```

Values to exlude from our minimum search

```
exclude <- c(0,1,2,3)
```

we can find the minimum value from column `a` excluding our `exclude` vector

```
## minimum from column a
min(df[!df$a %in% exclude,]$a)
# [1] 4
```

Or from `b`

```
exclude <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
min(df[!df$b %in% exclude,]$b)
# [1] 50
```

To return the row that corresponds to the minimum value

```
df[df$b == min( df[ !df$b %in% exclude, ]$b ),]
#   a  b
# 9 5 50
```

**Update**

To find the minimum across multiple rows we can do it this way:

```
## values to exclude
exclude_a <- c(0,1)
exclude_b <- c(10)

## exclude rows/values from each column we don't want
df2 <- df[!(df$a %in% exclude_a) & !(df$b %in% exclude_b),]

## order the data 
df3 <- df2[with(df2, order(a,b)),]

## take the first row
df3[1,]
# > df3[1,]
# a  b
#4 2 20
```

**Update 2**

To select from multiple columns we can iterate over them as @akrun has shown, or alternatively we can construct our subsetting formula using an `expression` and `eval`uate it inside our `[` operation

```
exclude <- c(0,1,2, 10)

## construct a formula/expression using the column names
n <- names(df)
expr <- paste0("(", paste0(" !(df$", n, " %in% exclude) ", collapse = "&") ,")")
# [1] "( !(df$a %in% exclude) & !(df$b %in% exclude) )"
expr <- parse(text=expr)

df2 <- df[eval(expr),]

## order and select first row as before
df2 <- df2[with(df2, order(a,b)),]
df2 <- df2[1,]
```

And if we wanted to use `data.table` for this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ eval(expr) ][order(a, b),][1,]
```

**comparison of methods**

```
library(microbenchmark)

fun_1 <- function(x){
  df2 <- x[eval(expr),]

  ## order and select first row as before
  df2 <- df2[with(df2, order(a,b)),]
  df2 <- df2[1,]
  return(df2)
}

fun_2 <- function(x){
  df2 <- setDT(x)[ eval(expr) ][order(a, b),][1,]
  return(df2)
}

## including @akrun's solution
fun_3 <- function(x){
  setDT(df)
  MinVal <- vector('list', length(df))
  for(j in seq_along(df)){
    setkeyv(df, names(df)[j])
    MinVal[[j]] <- min(df[!.(exclude)][[j]])
  }
  return(MinVal)
}

microbenchmark(fun_1(df), fun_2(df), fun_3(df) , times=1000)
 # Unit: microseconds
 #     expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
 # fun_1(df)  770.376  804.5715  866.3499  833.071  869.2195 2728.740  1000
 # fun_2(df)  854.862  893.1220  952.1207  925.200  962.6820 3115.119  1000
 # fun_3(df) 1108.316 1148.3340 1233.1268 1186.938 1234.3570 5400.544  1000
```

Comment: Thanks @tospig I suppose to find the minimum across all columns, we need to use sapply using the above mechanism?

Comment: Thanks @topsig … but if there are many rows and columns … we need some way to iterate and pick

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `data.table` (as the OP mentioned about data table in the post) after setting the `key`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key='a')[!.(exclude)]
#   a  b
#1: 4 40
#2: 5 50
#3: 6 60
```

If we need the `min` value of 'a'

```
min(setDT(df, key='a')[!.(exclude)]$a)
#[1] 4
```

For finding the `min` in all the columns (using the `setkey` method), we loop over the columns of the dataset, set the key as each of the column, subset the dataset, get the `min` value in a previously created `list` object.

```
setDT(df)
MinVal <- vector('list', length(df))
for(j in seq_along(df)){
 setkeyv(df, names(df)[j])
 MinVal[[j]] <- min(df[!.(exclude)][[j]])
}

MinVal
#[[1]]
#[1] 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 10
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(0,2,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6),
             b = c(10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,50,60))
exclude <- c(0,1,2,3)
```